# How can I consistently redirect a small subset of website traffic to a new beta site?

Tags: networking

I had ideally wanted to do this by geolocation (IPs in the US are the only ones that get redirected) but learned that without an expensive set-up or some pretty hefty engineering, this would not work.

Can someone else suggest (other than by specific URL re-routes) any way I might group/identify a subset of users to be consistently redirected to the new beta website?  The best case scenario is that those people are permanently re-routed until ALL traffic is eventually re-routed to the new site. The worst case scenario would be that people get bounced back and forth randomly between the sites each time they visit (which would be very bad news because the two sites are completely different).

Any thoughts or links to resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated! I'm a noob to network related topics..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the target site **once** in a cookie, for example for every 10th request not having the target site set.

Then use URL rewriting based on that cookie value.

You could possibly squeeze all this in your .htaccess file if using Apache, see http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html